# May somebody please help me to code a text-box that will inform the user of his/her total attempts for a guessing game

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm stuck on the last part of my code in which I need to create a text-box that will display the users number of attempts. What I don't understand is how exactly to get the text-box to display the attempts. I have included the code. Thank you

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<FORM NAME="testform">
<BR>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" VALUE="Click to Guess" onClick="testButton(this.form)">
<BR>
</FORM>

<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">

function testButton (form){

varguess = prompt("Guess a number betweent 1 and 20.","")
varattempts = 0


switch(true)

{

case varguess == 14:
    alert("You guessed right!")
    break;
case varguess>0 && varguess<=13:
    alert("Try again!")
    varattempts = varattempts + 1
    break;
case varguess>14 && varguess<=20:
    alert("Try again!")
    varattempts = varattempts + 1
    break;
default:
    alert("Please pick a number between 1 and 20.")


}

 }

</SCRIPT>
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="inputbox" VALUE="Attempts " + varattempts">
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: <s>Do you mean text-box as in the one `alert()` provides? `alert()` should work when you put `attempts` there instead of a string.</s> Never mind, you edited the code.

Comment: Sorry, could you please explain that a bit more? The text input at the bottom of the code is where the number of attempts should output

Comment: Change input to `<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="inputbox" VALUE="Attempts" id="attempts_box">` and after varattempts = varattempts + 1; (which, btw, could be written as varattempts++; add the following line `document.getElementById('attempts_box').value = varattempts;` You may even remove `varattempts++;` by `document.getElementById('attempts_box').value = (++varattempts);` and do not forget to write `var varattempts = 0;` before the `function testButton (form){`, not after it.

Comment: Your variable `attmepts` is out of scope. You can't use it after the script ends. You'll have to include it into the script via what Cheery just said.

Comment: How would I reset the attempts back to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't completely rewrite your code, but is this the desired effect: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d4UNe/)**

I added an ID to your input field to make grabbing it easier so the HTML is:

```
<FORM NAME="testform">
<BR>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" VALUE="Click to Guess" onClick="testButton(this.form)">
<BR>
</FORM>
<INPUT id="attempts" TYPE="text" NAME="inputbox" VALUE="Attempts " />
```

BTW tags arenormally coded in lowercase (e.g. `<form>` instead of `<FORM>`)

And the JavaScript is:

```
var varattempts = 0
function testButton(form) {

varguess = prompt("Guess a number betweent 1 and 20.", "")

switch (true)
    {
    case varguess == 14:
        alert("You guessed right!")
        break;
    case varguess > 0 && varguess <= 13:
        alert("Try again!")
        varattempts = varattempts + 1
        break;
    case varguess > 14 && varguess <= 20:
        alert("Try again!")
        varattempts = varattempts + 1
        break;
    default:
        alert("Please pick a number between 1 and 20.")    
    }
    document.getElementById('attempts').value = 'Attempts: '+varattempts;
}
```

Note that you need to move your varattempts variable outside of your function otherwise you're always initializing it to 1 whenever you call it.

Comment: Do I keep my input text box? I put this code into mine but the text still stays blank

Comment: Did you check out the HTML I posted? I added an id attribute to it (`<INPUT id="attempts" TYPE="text" NAME="inputbox" VALUE="Attempts " />`)

Comment: And how would I make a reset button to reset the attempts back to 0?

Comment: Try this updated jsFiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/d4UNe/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/d4UNe/2/). I added a reset button and a function to reset the counter and update the text.

Comment: Thank you very much the code works now! I'm still kind of confused on how you came up with the code do you think you could kind of explain what it does and the purpose?

Comment: I don't think there's enough room in these comment fields to do a full breakdown of the code. I can say though that I would rewrite most of that using jQuery and clean things up a bit. What I provided was just enough to get you going. If you found this helpful, please consider choosing it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
case varguess>14 && varguess<=20:
    alert("Try again!")
    varattempts = varattempts + 1
    document.getElemensByName('inputbox')[0].value = 'Attempts ' +  varattempts;
    break;
```

you should do this for all your cases  of failed attempts.

your input-text does not have an id attribute, so we have to select it by the name attribute with

```
document.getElementsByName('inputbox')
```

getElementsByName returns an HTML List(kind of like an array), containing ALL the elements with the name 'inputbox'. in this case you only have one, but you get the list anyway.

in that way, you have to access your input box, using the index 0, to refer to the first item. if you had an array list=['a','b','c'] you would get 'a' by calling list[0].

then you ask to change it's value with .value = 'Attempts ' + varattempts.

I hope you understand it now

Comment: Sorry I'm a beginner programmer and that line is really confusing for me.

Comment: ok, your code is a bit cloggy, i noticed the begginer part. no problem. i will explain it in the edit

Comment: Yea I kind of understand it now, how would I make a reset button to set the attempts back to 0